# python | heroku | how to access packages over ssh

Tags: python, heroku, ssh, pip

Hi heroku python people,

I want my heroku app to access shared private libraries in my github account.

So I would like to have a requirements.txt file that looks like this ...

```
# requirements.txt
requests==1.2.2
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/jtushman/dict_digger.git#egg=dict_digger
```

And I would like it to use a ssh key that I upload with `heroku keys:add`  or have some mechanism to get a private key from the heroku cli.

Right now I get the following error (which is I guess expected):

**Host key verification failed.**

It does work if I do (per @kenneth_reitz's https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136665/192791):

```
-e git+https://username:password@github.com/jtushman/dict_digger.git#egg=dict_digger
```

But it is really unworkable for me to put credentials in my requirements.txt file

Has anyone come up with a nice solution for this?

---

I have also posted an issue on the heroku python buildpack project [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/97)

Comment: I am beginning to feel that this is not possible

Comment: I generated an oauth token and I use that with the https git repo. then you can just copy-paste the oauth key into the url in `.gitmodules` instead of exposing your private key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenneth, the maintainer of heroku's python buildpack said the following (and I am cutting and pasting here)

> I would currently recommend the way mentioned (git over https)
>
> Using the key you have registered with heroku would be cool, but
>   unfortunately, you would have to provide your private key for this to
>   work. Quite undesirable.
>
> However, you could also write your keys into a .ssh folder in your app
>   or use .profile scripts to facilitate this.

Can see the full thread here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/97

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before I wanted to use django-avatar and the version in PyPI is old and doesn't support Django 1.5 Custom User .

The simple solution is to download the package and use it as a regular app as if it was part of your project then just git add . and push it and it works !

It might not be the best idea but it just works .